# Shapefile doesn't fit with basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I had a dwg file without spatial reference. I converted it to shapefile and gave it a projection: WGS84, but when a try to open the basemap doesn't fit with the shapefile.

I think there's a problem with the projection, but I don't know how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: You need to get the exact coordinate reference system that the DWG file was created in.  You also need to know the scale the DWG was created in (m, mm, etc.).  Without that information you are not going to be able to properly project your data and you will have to manually adjust it using spatial adjustment or something similar.

Comment: Ok, thanks!
I will try to get that information. In case I get it, how can i project the dwg or the shapefile? I know how to give the proper projection, but i dont know how to scale the data.

Comment: For a shapefile with undefined coordinate system, once you know what it is (from the download source), you can use `Define Projection` to set the projection.  If you want to then change the projection to something else, `Project` the data (in Data Management toolbox)

Comment: smiller, i used that tools to define the projection, which is WGS84, but i think the problem is the scale, if u see the arcmap graphic in the post, the scale make no sense

Comment: The plain WGS84 crs uses Degrees as units. It is a Geographic coordinate system. It naturally creates huge scale distorsions if you assign that system. Your dwg most likely uses a linear unit (meters, feet...) and there is probably a benchmark or some reference point that the drawing uses. If no benchmark, units and coordinate system is stated, you will have to [Spatial Adjust](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment.htm) it as @jbalk said

Comment: Send me an email, mkennedy at esri dot com. I have two documents which may help explain what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: From my experience, you may need to change the scale in a CAD program.  When I received data like this I was usually able to work with the provider to get the scale and projection corrected on the provider's end.  If you are able to do that, then you can just define the projection and it will project in the correct location.

Comment: @mkennedy, i sent you an email to mkennedy@esri.com, is that correct?

Comment: @FSimardGIS, I changed the projection to UTM and I fixed the scale, but when I open the basemap, it doesnt show. I will take contact with the provider of the data to get the scale and projection corrected, just as jbalk said. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: When I open the shapefile with the UTM projection, ArcMAP sent me an error message that said the extent is inconsistent with the associated spatial reference information

Comment: @warforterritory Received and replied!